# Convert integer to string assembly 8086 tasm

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I'm using assembly 8086 16BIT with tasm assembler.
I'm trying to print an int variable, and to do so I need to converet my variable contant to string. I tried to build a procedure that do this without success. its completely wrong and not working.

can you help me build this/explain how to build this?

Thanks guys!

This is my base code right now:

```
stepCounter     db  0   
push offset stepCounter ; Copy the OFFSET of "parameter" into the stack
call toString

proc    toStringPrint
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov  ax, [bp + 4] ;number
    div 10; div number(in ax) by 10
    mov [bx], ah

    ;mov  dx, []
    ;mov  ah, 9h
    ;int  21h

    pop bp
    ret 4
endp    toString
```

**EDIT**

thanks! this is my code now: but its still not print nothing

```
proc    toStringPrint
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov si, [bp+4];number
    mov ax, [si]
divide:
    cmp al, 0
    je Print
    mov cl, 10
    div cl; div number(in ax) by 10
    mov [bx], ah
    dec bx  
    jmp divide

Print:  
    mov  dx, [bp + 6]
    mov  ah, 9h
    int  21h

    pop bp
    ret 4
endp    toStringPrint
```

**EDIT 2**
This is the current code, still crash the application and always print 219:

```
stepCounter     dW  0

;this is how i call the PROC:
mov cx, [stepCounter]
push cx   
call toStringPrint

proc    toStringPrint
    push bp
    mov bp, sp

    mov si, [bp+4] ;number location in memory( I think )
    mov ax, [si]

    mov cl, "$"
    mov [bx], cl
divide:
    mov ah, 0
    mov cl, 10
    div cl         ; div number(in ax) by 10
    dec bx
    add ah, 48     ;Make into a character
    mov [bx], ah  
    cmp al, 0
    jne divide
Print:  
    mov dx, bx
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h

    pop bp
    ret 4
endp    toStringPrint
```

Comment: Please show us the code that is wrong and not working. That would give us something to work with. Now your question is eligible for closure.

Comment: @SepRoland Thanks! I edit the post!

Comment: There's no `div immediate`. Move 10 into `bx`, say, and do `div bx` - also, remember to clear `dx` before the `div` as it's `dx:ax` that gets divided.

Comment: Also [Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45904075) - a canonical answer with 16-bit and 32-bit integers in 16-bit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer just addresses your **EDIT 2**.

> ```
> mov cx, [stepCounter]
> push cx   
> call toStringPrint
> ```

This code pushes the actual value of your *stepCounter* but in the procedure you treat it as the address of your *stepCounter*. Just start the *toStringPrint* proc with:

```
proc    toStringPrint
 push bp
 mov bp, sp
 mov ax, [bp+4] ;Value of stepCounter
```

---

> ```
>  pop bp
>  ret 4
> endp    toStringPrint
> ```

This code returns and removes an extra 4 bytes from the stack but you only pushed 2 bytes on the stack! Change this to:

```
 pop bp
 ret 2
endp    toStringPrint
```

---

You've not shown this but do make sure that BX points at the last byte of a suitable buffer. A 4-byte buffer will suffice.

Comment: Glad to see that you got it working! Please remember to _upvote_ answers that helped you. I would suggest though that you _accept_ the answer by @SepRoland since he did the most work.

Comment: thanks again :)
I up voted but it said : "Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score." :(

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> mov  ax, [bp + 4] ;number
> ```

The comment on this line is wrong. At `[bp+4]` you'll find the address of the *stepCounter* not its value! Use something like:

```
mov si, [bp+4]
mov ax, [si]
```

Also make your *stepCounter* a **word** in stead of a **byte**.

```
stepCounter     dw  0
```

The `div` instruction can't use an immediate operand. Move the value to a register beforehand. Use `CL` since it seems you want to use `BX` for storing the result:

```
mov cl, 10
div cl
```

---

Your edit gets close to a solution! I don't see what you expect at `[bp+6]`. The first step is to close the forthcoming string with a **$** sign and then start adding digits. To always show at least 1 digit do the test at the end. Never forget to zero the AH register before doing the division:

```
  mov cl, "$"
  mov [bx], cl
divide:
  mov ah, 0
  mov cl, 10
  div cl         ; div number(in ax) by 10
  dec bx
  add ah, 48     ;Make into a character
  mov [bx], ah  
  cmp al, 0
  jne divide
Print:  
  mov dx, bx
  mov ah, 9h
  int 21h
```

Comment: thank you!! but i still have problems, can you see the edit 2? @Sep Roland